# Concatenate lines with previous line based on number of letters in first column

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, csv, concatenation

New to coding and trying to figure out how to fix a broken csv file to make be able to work with it properly.

So the file has been exported from a case management system and contains fields for username, casenr, time spent, notes and date.

The problem is that occasional notes have newlines in them and when exporting the csv the tooling does not contain quotation marks to define it as a string within the field.

see below example:

```
user;case;hours;note;date;
tnn;123;4;solved problem;2017-11-27;
tnn;124;2;random comment;2017-11-27;
tnn;125;3;I am writing a comment
that contains new lines
without quotation marks;2017-11-28;
HJL;129;8;trying to concatenate lines to re form the broken csv;2017-11-29;
```

I would like to concatenate lines 3,4 and 5 to show the following:
tnn;125;3;I am writing a comment that contains new lines without quotation marks;2017-11-28;

Since every line starts with a username (always 3 letters) I thought I would be able to iterate the lines to find which lines do not start with a username and concatenate that with the previous line.
It is not really working as expected though.

This is what I have got so far:

```
import re

with open('Rapp.txt', 'r') as f:

 for line in f:
  previous = line #keep current line in variable to join next line
  if not re.match(r'^[A-Za-z]{3}', line): #regex to match 3 letters
   print(previous.join(line))
```

Script shows no output just finishes silently, any thoughts?

Comment: What happens if the comment contains a `;`? Maybe you should try to fix the CSV export instead, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would go a slightly different way:

```
import re

all_the_data = ""

with open('Rapp.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not re.search("\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2};\n", line):
            line = re.sub("\n", "", line)
        all_the_data = "".join([all_the_data, line])
print (all_the_data)
```

There a several ways to do this each with pros and cons, but I think this keeps it simple.

Loop the file as you have done and if the line doesn't end in a date and ; take off the carriage return and stuff it into all_the_data.  That way you don't have to play with looking back 'up' the file.  Again, lots of way to do this.  If you would rather use the logic of starts with 3 letters and a ; and looking back, this works:

```
import re

all_the_data = ""

with open('Rapp.txt', 'r') as f:
    all_the_data = ""
    for line in f:
        if not re.search("^[A-Za-z]{3};", line):
            all_the_data = re.sub("\n$", "", all_the_data)
        all_the_data = "".join([all_the_data, line])

    print ("results:")
    print (all_the_data)
```

Pretty much what was asked for.  The logic being if the current line doesn't start right, take out the previous line's carriage return from all_the_data.

If you need help playing with the regex itself, this site is great:  http://regex101.com

Comment: I went with the second solution as the real file contained some more fields last one not being date.

That value was sometimes empty as well making it difficult using the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

The regex in your code matches to all the lines (string) in the txt (finds a valid match to the pattern). The if condition is never true and hence nothing prints.

```
with open('./Rapp.txt', 'r') as f:
    join_words = []

    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if len(line) > 3 and ";" in line[0:4] and len(join_words) > 0:
            print(';'.join(join_words)) 
            join_words = []
            join_words.append(line)
        else:
            join_words.append(line)

    print(";".join(join_words))
```

I've tried to not use regex here to keep it a little clear if possible. But, regex is a better option.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to use a generator that acts as a filter on the original file. That filter would concatenate a line to the previous one if it has not a semicolon (`;`) in its 4th column. Code could be:

```
def preprocess(fd):
    previous = next(fd)
    for line in fd:
        if line[3] == ';':
            yield previous
            previous = line
        else:
            previous = previous.strip() + " " + line
    yield previous  # don't forget last line!
```

You could then use:

```
with open(test.txt) as fd:
    rd = csv.DictReader(preprocess(fd))
    for row in rd:
        ...
```

The trick here is that the csv module only requires on object that returns a line each time `next` function is applied to it, so a generator is appropriate.

But this is only a workaround and the correct way would be that the previous step directly produces a correct CSV file.